# How to write AlertDialog for Buttons dynamically generated in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-alertdialog, android-button

I have a few GridView objects, like "battlegrid" and "handfield" that are instantiated in my PlayGameAcvitity (they are parts of the layout displayed during the PlayGameActivity). The gridviews are populated dynamically with buttons from a custom Adapter I have written. I would like to have an AlertDialog with several options (list form from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)) appear when the buttons are long-pressed. I'm not sure how to go about doing this as all the examples I've seen have been implemented in an activity class. However, my LongClickListeners for the buttons are inside the Adapter code.

Here is part of the battlegrid gridview's adapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    Button btn;
    .
    .
    .
    btn.setLongClickable(true); //enable long press
     btn.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
     {
         @Override
         public boolean onLongClick(View v)
         {
             //TODO: make alertdialog appear and do stuff with what was selected
             return true;
         } 
     });
    .
    .
    .
    return btn;
}
```

The code for "handfield"'s adapter and the others is similar. I need to be able to bring up an AlertDialog with a list of options here, and implement what happens depending on what is selected. The AlertDialog that appears for a button long-pressed in "battlegrid" needs to be different from the one that appears for a button long-pressed in "handfield." Is there a way to do this? If this is impossible for AlertDialogs is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a **Listener** and send that to your adapter. when you override **onLongClick** of btn in getView, call method of Listener. and implement that method in your activity. so you can bring up an AlertDialog in that. look at this:

in activity:

```
private YourListener listener = new YourListener() {
    @Override
    public void onListLongClick(long id, GridType type) {
        // bring up an AlertDialog according to GridType
    }
}
```

you must define a **YourListener interface** before that. and send this **listener** variable to your adapter.

and in adapter call that:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    Button btn;
    .
    .
    .
    btn.setLongClickable(true); //enable long press
    btn.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
             listener.onListLongClick(getItemId(), GridType.battlegrid);
             return true;
        } 
    });
    .
    .
    .
    return btn;
}
```